# How to edit position of Navigation bar button?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I want to add custom button in Navigation bar.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add a button to UINavigationBar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504351/how-to-add-a-button-to-uinavigationbar)

Answer (score 2):

Because of the Apple Human Interface Guidelines, you can't have a custom position for an instance of a button on UINavigationBar. It has to go in the corners of the screen, and even if you can manage to move it, Apple will not let the application into the App Store.

Comment: Can you please mention any link in apple site for this statement? It will be useful for further study... Thanks in advance
Please go through this link.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6169474/ios-positioning-navigation-bar-buttons-within-custom-navigation-bar

Comment: The human interface guidelines are only avaliable for registered developers. I suggest trying to download a copy from Google. They are abundantly avaliable. If you are a developer, than you can access the guide from developer.apple.com

Comment: HIG are publicly available. https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/overview/themes/