# iOS: Positioning navigation bar buttons within custom navigation bar

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, frontend

I'm building an app with a custom navigation bar. After some research I decided to do this using a category on UINavigationBar. The navigation bar needs to be a bit larger than usual to accomodate a drop shadow. Here is the code:

```
#import "UINavigationBar+CustomWithShadow.h"

@implementation UINavigationBar (CustomWithShadow)

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    // Change the tint color in order to change color of buttons
    UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithHue:0.0 saturation:0.0 brightness:0.0 alpha:0.0];
    self.tintColor = color;

    // Add a custom background image to the navigation bar 
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"NavBar.png"];
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, 60)];
}

- (void)layoutSubviews {

    self.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, self.frame.size.width, 60);
}
@end
```

The only problem now is that the larger navigation bar means that the navigation bar buttons end up too far down, like so:

[image]

Does anyone know how I can correct the position of the buttons?

Thanks for all help!

**Update:**

I add the buttons to the nav bar in the init method of the view controller like so:

```
// Create "Add" button for the nav bar
UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
    initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd 
    target:self 
    action:@selector(createNewEntry:)];
[[self navigationItem] setRightBarButtonItem:addButton];
[addButton release];
```

Comment: How do you add the `UIBarButtonItem` to the bar? And where? I made a small test in which I add the btns via NIBs and everything seems OK.

Comment: I add them in the init method of the view controller, using `[[self navigationItem] setRightBarButtonItem:addButton];` for example. How can I add the buttons via NIBs?

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to add the leftBarButtonItem and rightBarButtonItem as custom items and mess with the frames.... for example:

```
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,5,buttonImage.size.width,buttonImage.size.height)];
[button setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:delegate action:@selector(barButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button setTitle:titleString forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setTitleColor:CUSTOM_BAR_BUTTON_TITLE_COLOR forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[[button titleLabel] setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14]];
[[button titleLabel] setShadowColor:CUSTOM_BAR_BUTTON_SHADOW_COLOR];
[[button titleLabel] setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0,-1)];

UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
[button release];

[[self navigationItem] setRightBarButtonItem:barButton];
[barButton release];
```

Comment: Is there a simpler way? I've got buttons on subsequent views and would like to avoid adding each of them as a custom item if possible. Feel free to suggest alternatives to the way I added the drop shadow to the navigation bar if you have any :)

Comment: @Erik You will have to use a customView-bar-button-item taking the actual button as a subview to fix such offset issues.

Comment: A simpler way to achieve this on all navigation button would be to create a subclass or category of UINavigationBarButton.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea adam! Do you know which methods I would need to override and how, or do you know where I would go to find that information?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the buttons to the nav bar in the `viewDidLoad` method of the view controller instead.

Comment: No change I'm afraid. The buttons continue to align themselves to the bottom of the navigation bar (which goes down to the end of the drop shadow).

Answer (score 0):

My solution, not the best, but it works for me fine. My custom navigation bar has height 55 (default height is 44). I cut from my custom navigation bar only 44 of height and insert it to the navigation bar. Then I cut next part of my custom navigation bar (shadows etc.) and insert it as image view under the navigation bar. And that's it. Buttons are at right places...