# iOS: Is is possible to make a UINavigationBar taller and "push" the other views down the screen?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

**Is there a way to make the "content" area of an iPhone app aware of a larger navigation bar?**

Similar to these questions:

- [iOS: Adding a fixed image just below the navigation bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6167871/ios-adding-a-fixed-image-just-below-the-navigation-bar)
- [iOS: Positioning navigation bar buttons within custom navigation bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6169474/ios-positioning-navigation-bar-buttons-within-custom-navigation-bar)

I've managed to use the 1st questions sample code to add a category on UINavigationBar and change its height, and added a subview where I need it, but I can't see a way to cause the UITableView (or indeed any content views) to take its height into consideration:

[image: iPhone 4 Simulator Screenshot]
(The colors are only to make the different views distinguishable)

Comment: +1 for "(The colors are only to make the different views distinguishable)" because otherwise I would vote to close :) <— joke

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The accepted answer to the first question sets the nav bar's frame in -layoutSubviews, which is anywhere from "ewwwww" to outright wrong depending on the assumptions made by other layout code.

Instead, override -sizeThatFits: to return a more appropriate size.

Comment: We have a winner! I return the required size from sizeThatFits, and everything gets resized properly. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

I'd go about this by adjusting the tableView.frame, so something like this:

```
CGRect navFrame = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame;

CGRect tableFrame = self.tableView.frame;

tableFrame.size.height = tableFrame.size.height - navFrame.size.height;
tableFrame.origin.y = navFrame.size.height; //move it down by the height covered by the navigation Bar

self.tableView.frame = tableFrame;
```

You could do this with your other views as well - i.e. by simply adjusting the frame.

I've not got XCode on this computer, so I've not checked the code - just written it out as an example, so please check it yourself before using it!

Comment: This really isn't a viable approach as soon as there are even a handful of different views. I'd have to implement this on every ViewController!

Comment: -1. The navigation controller's view will get laid out periodically (e.g. on rotation changes); layout hacks like this will often appear to work until you do something unexpected like rotating the device or pushing/popping another VC. I've needed to do this on one occasion, but there are generally more reliable ways of achieving this.