# Is my Navigation Bar a violation of IOS Human Interface Guidelines

Tags: ios, appstore-approval

I wanted to reposition the left and right buttons of the Navigation Bar such that there are three and they're equally spaced. To do so I looked at this question for reference: [stackover flow - How to edit position of navigation bar button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226047/how-to-edit-position-of-navigation-bar-button). I managed to solve it by my self by changing the size of the frames for the buttons so it looks like the following:

[My Navigation Bar (Black and white boxes are buttons in the navigation bar)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fTSW.png)

However, the post said that if I were to break the HIG then my application will be removed from the app store. So I was wondering to what extent is this true (as I didnt have to break Xcode to achieve what I wanted) and if what I have now is safe.

Here is the code I have :

```
viewDidLoad() {

    let todolistButton = UIButton(type: .system)
    todolistButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    todolistButton.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: (view.frame.width-50)/3, height: 44)
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: todolistButton)

    let scheduleButton = UIButton(type: .system)
    scheduleButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    scheduleButton.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: (view.frame.width-50)/3, height: 44)

    let calendarButton = UIButton(type: .system)
    calendarButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    calendarButton.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: ((view.frame.width-50)/3)+2, height: 44)

    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [UIBarButtonItem(customView: scheduleButton), UIBarButtonItem(customView: calendarButton)]
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Generally Apple doesn't actually reject apps for breaking the HIG.

However, your solution has a problem: you're using `view.frame.width` in `viewDidLoad`. The view's size might not be correct at that time. You cannot rely on the view's size to be correct until `viewWillLayoutSubviews`.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the quick reply and for the advice as well!