# Draw custom Back button on iPhone Navigation Bar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, back-button

I've got a UIView with a NavigationBar and I'd like to add a button which looks like the style of a Back Button. I'm not using a UINavigationController and was wondering if this could be done without it?

The style of the button should look like this: [image]

Thanks

Comment: @casperOne Aside from closing a question nearly 2 years after it was answered, why did you close this? The accepted answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/227078 suggests using an image, whereas the answer below by Mike Weller is far more elegant. Not to mention, the answer here will support newer devices (for example, I did not change this code example when the retina display was launched and it still works. An image would show a low-res finish).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to set up a custom stack of `UINavigationItem` objects and push them on to the UINavigationBar. This is the only way I know of to get a true back button. I haven't tested this code, but you should do something like this:

```
UINavigationItem *previousItem =
    [[[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back title"] autorelease];

UINavigationItem *currentItem =
    [[[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Main Title"] autorelease];

[navigationBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:previousItem, currentItem, nil]
               animated:YES];
```

To handle when the buttons are pressed you should set yourself as the navigation bar's delegate and implement the UINavigationBarDelegate delegates.

Comment: FYI: setting the delegate of a navigationBar managed by a navigationController raises an exception: `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Cannot manually set the delegate on a UINavigationBar managed by a controller.'`

Comment: what is the currentItem?

Answer (score 1):

You can also update this by modifying the `backBarButtonItem` on the previous view controller (not the currently viewed one).

Comment: Hi, i think your answer can help me in my problem, please how to use the backBarButtonItem in my code, assuming that this is my code in the previous view: -(IBAction)goToRechercherView {
 
 rechercherViewController.modalTransitionStyle=UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
 
 [self  presentModalViewController:rechercherViewController animated:YES];
 
}