# UIBarButtonItem not being added to navigation

Tags: objective-c, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem

I am unable to set the left button in my navigation bar. Anyone have an idea why the code below is not displaying a button?

```
UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
 initWithTitle:@"my left button" 
 style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
 target:nil 
 action:nil];


[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:barButton];

 //this is now printing out "my left button", 
 //but the button still does not appear on the navigation.
 NSLog(@"navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.title:
  %@",self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.title);
```

Interface Builder:

[image]

Simulator:

[image]

---UPDATE----

The above code is updated with correct enum and init based on CodaFi's suggestions but the button is still not appearing.

Comment: What is navigationItem and where have you defined and initialized it?

Comment: The posted code is in the viewDidLoad of my subclass of a UIViewController. navigationItem is a property of UIViewController, do I need to initialize it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `initWithBarButtonSystemItem:` part of your init method is being supplied the wrong enum value.

System items are different from bar button styles (case in point UIBarButtonItem**Style**Bordered, vs UIBarButton**System**ItemAdd).

Here is the list of valid enum values:

> typedef enum {
>      UIBarButtonSystemItemDone,
>      UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel,
>      UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit,
>      UIBarButtonSystemItemSave,
>      UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd,
>      UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace,
>      UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace,
>      UIBarButtonSystemItemCompose,
>      UIBarButtonSystemItemReply,
>      UIBarButtonSystemItemAction,
>      UIBarButtonSystemItemOrganize,
>      UIBarButtonSystemItemBookmarks,
>      UIBarButtonSystemItemSearch,
>      UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh,
>      UIBarButtonSystemItemStop,
>      UIBarButtonSystemItemCamera,
>      UIBarButtonSystemItemTrash,
>      UIBarButtonSystemItemPlay,
>      UIBarButtonSystemItemPause,
>      UIBarButtonSystemItemRewind,
>      UIBarButtonSystemItemFastForward,
>      UIBarButtonSystemItemUndo,        // iOS 3.0 and later
>      UIBarButtonSystemItemRedo,        // iOS 3.0 and later
>      UIBarButtonSystemItemPageCurl

Comment: What enum value should be passed in?

Comment: I just changed it to UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered and the log is still printing null

Comment: Yeah, that's the point.  It's a style, not a system item.  You're using the wrong init method then.  Use initWithTitle:style:target:action: instead for style

Comment: The button is still not appearing. Do I need to somehow link my Navigation Bar or Navigation Item from my xib file to my implementation file?

Comment: I've never heard of someone making a Navigation controller in a XIB.  update your question with what you just tried.

Comment: I have updated my question and added screenshots. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I SEE!  You have made a nav bar in IB which is not automatically set to self.navgationController, so the real navigation controller that you've been trying to add a bar item to doesn't exist!  You need to do one of two things:  write a nav bar in code in the App Delegate and delete the XIB one, or make a reference to the XIB nav bar and add the button to it.

Comment: ahhh okay... How do I make a reference to the XIB nav bar?

Comment: Make an IBOutlet for one.  That's your new nav controller.  Beware, though, the controller has relevance only within this view controller.  Declare one in the app delegate if you need to go deeper than one level with a Push.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I am not pushing at all, this VC is displayed in a modal using presentModalViewController.

Comment: Excellent.  Happy coding.  And if you wouldn't mind up voting and accepting?

Comment: Thanks, UINavigationBar does not have the method setLeftBarButtonItem. So I am not sure what to use.

Comment: I think this is what I need for that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504351/how-to-add-a-button-to-uinavigationbar

Comment: Yes, exactly.  UINavigationItem is an annoying class to use, but it's necessary in your case.

Comment: Maybe I am going about it the wrong way. Do I need to use UINavigationItem in order to have custom buttons?

Comment: Yes.  If you were to set this up in the app delegate; then an internal UINavigationItem would have been set up for you, but because you are using a XIB, you must define your own.  It'll work great.