# Create a title and button on navigation bar

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I am trying to replicate iPhone's Contacts application and to create a button over navigation bar. Actually the view is not a `UINavigation` controller. I just added the navigation bar programatically but I am struggling to create a title and a button on that navigation bar.

I am using the following code

```
[[UIBarButton alloc]] initWithTitle:@"Done" 
                              Style:UIBarButonItemStyleBorderd 
                              target:Self 
                              action:selector(btnClicked)];  
self.navigationItem.rightBArButtonItem=btnDone; 
[self.view addSubview:navigationBar];
```

Please refer iphone contact application in simulator.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: On StackOverflow, it is recommended that you put a bit of code and explain more in details what you have tried so far.

Comment: sorry i dont have net access in my mac system so it is not possible to put code..

Comment: what is the problem u r facing? do u wanna add BarButtonitem?

Comment: i tried allocating [[UIBarButton alloc]] initWithTitle:@"Done" Style:UIBarButonItemStyleBorderd target:Self action:selector(btnClicked)};

Comment: add what you have tried(code and error log) to ur Question to get better answers..

Comment: @ iShru the button is not visible. i tried the code you gave .is there any other option ?

Comment: @iShru ya i want to add barButton to navigation Bar. it is not a UINavigation Controller it is ordinary UIController i added that navigation bar programatically.

Comment: [[UIBarButton alloc]] initWithTitle:@"Done" Style:UIBarButonItemStyleBorderd target:Self action:selector(btnClicked)];     self.navigationItem.rightBArButtonItem=btnDone; [self.view addSubview:navigationBar];

Answer (score 0):

try this code chunk

```
UIBarButtonItem *rightButton = **[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" 
    style:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:nil action:nil];**
UINavigationItem *item = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title"];
item.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton;
item.hidesBackButton = YES;
[bar pushNavigationItem:item animated:NO];
[rightButton release];
[item release];
```

and go through other SO links like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504351/how-to-add-a-button-to-uinavigationbar)