# Multiple buttons in uinavigation

Tags: ipad, uinavigationcontroller, ios6, uinavigationbar

Is it possible to add multiple buttons in ui navigation bar in ipad basis application? as like in the image?Can any one pls help me with any refrence?

[image]

Comment: go through this link http://osmorphis.blogspot.in/2009/05/multiple-buttons-on-navigation-bar.html

Answer (score 0):

sure, you can, You can add buttons as `UIBarButtonItem`,
for more information, please check my answer at this page

[Navigation Bar or ToolBar trouble in xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13908977/navigation-bar-or-toolbar-trouble-in-xcode/13909341#13909341)

you can achieve what you need with light modifications

Regards

Answer (score 0):

A UINavigationBar is populated through a UINavigationItem. Typically this is the navigation item of a UIViewController (though it doesn't have to be). A UINavigationItem has `rightBarButtonItems` and `leftBarButtonItems`. Those are both plurals; you can give them each an array of bar button items.