# How do I an image at a specific location in a navigation bar?

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

Im customizing my navbars so they all have a logo in them.  I want to add the logo right around here:

[image: Image in Navbar]

I know navbars have a background image property but that would stretch it to the whole navbar.  I just want it  there! :)

So far Ive tried this:

```
UIImage *gradientImage44 = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"NavBar25High"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
    UIImage *gradientImage32 = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"NavBar25High"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
    // Set the background image for *all* UINavigationBars
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:gradientImage44 forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:gradientImage32 forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsLandscapePhone];
```

But thats for gradients because as I mentioned, it uses the image as a background image :(

Comment: @Wain I just edited the original post with what I tried. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would allocate an ImageView using CGRectMake to the specific location you want it and add that image view to the view of the UINavigationController.

Like this:

Declare the image

```
UIImage *myImage =[UIImage imageNamed:@"header.png"];
```

Allocate the image view

```
myImageView_tools = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(97.5, 20, 125, 45)];
```

Set the image as the image of the imageview

```
myImageView_tools.image = myImage;
```

Add this to your navbar.

```
[nameofyournavbar.view addSubview:myImageView_tools];
```

In my code I happened to add it to the RootViewController instead of the NavigationBar but I would imagine it would work just the same.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding the image as the custom view of a `UIBarButtonItem`. Maybe using a `UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace` item with a specified width.

Comment: I thought those were only for uitoolbars?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504351/how-to-add-a-button-to-uinavigationbar

Comment: Yes but that post adds buttons to navbars.  That I can do.  I would need to add something like a fixed space but fixed spaces are only for uitoolbars.  That's ok, I just made an image to use as gradient for the navbar :)

Comment: I can't say I've tried it but the documentation says "Items can include fixed-width and flexible-width spaces."